# how do I cancel print jobs for a specific month on unix

Tags: printing

how do I cancel print jobs for a specific month on unix 
such as

```
sudo cancel -e printernames month
```

This is the print queue text I want to process

```
EpsonP_URSB-4125    admingou       priority 0  Aug  9 14:49 on EpsonP_URSB
        o24683889.out                         3897 bytes
EpsonP_URSB-4126    admingou       priority 0  Aug  9 14:51
        o24683917.out                         3897 bytes
EpsonP_URSB-4168    admingou       priority 0  Aug  9 16:40
        o24685868.out                         3873 bytes
EpsonP_URSB-4169    admingou       priority 0  Aug  9 16:49
        o24686042.out                         3873 bytes
EpsonP_URSB-4594    admingou       priority 0  Aug 15 14:02
        o24728095.out                         3873 bytes
EpsonP_URSB-4795    admingou       priority 0  Aug 16 15:32
        o24739409.out                         3942 bytes
EpsonP_URSB-6877    admingou       priority 0  Sep  2 08:11
        o24866057.out                         3909 bytes
EpsonP_URSB-9143    admingou       priority 0  Sep 19 08:36
        o25011121.out                         3873 bytes
EpsonP_URSB-9144    admingou       priority 0  Sep 19 08:40
        o25011183.out                         3899 bytes
EpsonP_URSB-9146    admingou       priority 0  Sep 19 08:44
        o25011237.out                         3922 bytes
EpsonP_URSB-9153    admingou       priority 0  Sep 19 08:57
        o25011532.out                         3873 bytes
EpsonP_URSB-9154    admingou       priority 0  Sep 19 08:58
        o25011538.out                         4118 bytes
EpsonP_URSB-9155    admingou       priority 0  Sep 19 08:58
        o25011542.out                         3893 bytes
EpsonP_URSB-9158    admingou       priority 0  Sep 19 09:19
        o25011789.out                         3967 bytes
EpsonP_URSB-9159    admingou       priority 0  Sep 19 09:22
        o25011836.out                         3967 bytes
EpsonP_URSB-9160    admingou       priority 0  Sep 19 09:23
        o25011907.out                         4060 bytes
EpsonP_URSB-9161    admingou       priority 0  Sep 19 09:24
        o25011930.out                         4015 bytes
```

Comment: In the general sense, you take the list of jobs from your print queue, filter (`grep`? `awk`?) for the jobs you want to cancel, extract the job ids (`awk`? `cut`?), and pass to `cancel`. If you can [edit] your question to provide a relevant extract from your print queue it becomes a simple exercise in text processing.

Comment: large number of jobs I want to cancel based on date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a line like this one from your printer queue:

> ```
> EpsonP_URSB-4126    admingou       priority 0  Aug  9 14:51
> ```

To match on the fifth field, and cancel the job id from the first field:

```
printer_queue_command | awk -v month=Aug '$5 == month { print $1 }' | xargs -r echo cancel
```

You may need to tweak the `cancel` command to include a printer queue. Remove `-r` if your version of `xargs` doesn't support it. Add `-n1` if you have to issue a `cancel` command for each job separately. Remove the `echo` when you're happy with the output.